# Dairy free popping candy?

Tags: chocolate, candy

I am looking to recreate a dairy free popping candy chocolate I have no issues creating the chocolate but I'm sure popping candy contains milk...

Is there such thing as a dairy free popping candy and if not is there any way I could make it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think so.

Milk sugars show up in the regular pop rocks ingredients list, and I also looked at the ingredients list for the culinary grade unflavored popping crystals, but those still contain milk sugars - it isn't just in the extra flavorings, but in the base material recipe.  And as far as I know, there's no real way to make this popping candy at home.

You can look up the homemade [carbonated candy](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/how-to-make-homemade-pop-rocks/) recipes that use citric acid and baking soda, but those tend to be [fizzing](http://www.instructables.com/id/Homemade-Fizzy-Pop-Rocks-Candy/), not popping, when activated.  It may be close enough for your purposes, and the recipe doesn't have milk in it, but names aside it is not the same candy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I can't have dairy and found [these dairy free ones on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B018MVH31M). I haven't received them yet, so can't vouch for the quality, but it's an option!